# Reading a list of Files as a Java 8 Stream

Tags: java, lazy-loading, java-stream, binaryfiles

I have a (possibly long) list of binary files that I want to read lazily.  There will be too many files to load into memory. I'm currently reading them as a MappedByteBuffer with `FileChannel.map()`, but that probably isn't required.  I want the method `readBinaryFiles(...)` to return a Java 8 Stream so I can lazy load the list of files as I access them.

```
    public List<FileDataMetaData> readBinaryFiles(
    List<File> files, 
    int numDataPoints, 
    int dataPacketSize )
    throws
    IOException {

    List<FileDataMetaData> fmdList = new ArrayList<FileDataMetaData>();

    IOException lastException = null;
    for (File f: files) {

        try {
            FileDataMetaData fmd = readRawFile(f, numDataPoints, dataPacketSize);
            fmdList.add(fmd);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("", e);
            lastException = e;
        }
    }

    if (null != lastException)
        throw lastException;

    return fmdList;
}


//  The List<DataPacket> returned will be in the same order as in the file.
public FileDataMetaData readRawFile(File file, int numDataPoints, int dataPacketSize) throws IOException {

    FileDataMetaData fmd;
    FileChannel fileChannel = null;
    try {
        fileChannel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r").getChannel();
        long fileSz = fileChannel.size();
        ByteBuffer bbRead = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) fileSz);
        MappedByteBuffer buffer = fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fileSz);

        buffer.get(bbRead.array());
        List<DataPacket> dataPacketList = new ArrayList<DataPacket>();

        while (bbRead.hasRemaining()) {

            int channelId = bbRead.getInt();
            long timestamp = bbRead.getLong();
            int[] data = new int[numDataPoints];
            for (int i=0; i<numDataPoints; i++) 
                data[i] = bbRead.getInt();

            DataPacket dp = new DataPacket(channelId, timestamp, data);
            dataPacketList.add(dp);
        }

        fmd = new FileDataMetaData(file.getCanonicalPath(), fileSz, dataPacketList);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("", e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (null != fileChannel) {
            try {
                fileChannel.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return fmd;
}
```

Returning `fmdList.Stream()` from `readBinaryFiles(...)` won't accomplish this because the file contents will already have been read into memory, which I won't be able to do.

The other approaches to reading the contents of multiple files as a Stream rely on using `Files.lines()`, but I need to read binary files.

I'm, open to doing this in Scala or golang if those languages have better support for this use case than Java.

I'd appreciate any pointers on how to read the contents of multiple binary files lazily.

Comment: Do you want to read the files as one long, continuous stream of bytes?

Comment: `return files.stream().map(f -> readRawFile(f, numDataPoints, dataPacketSize))` will be sufficient… if you remove `throws IOException` from the readRawFile method’s signature.  You could have that method catch IOException internally and wrap it in an [UncheckedIOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html).  (The problem with deferred execution is that the exceptions also need to be deferred.)

Comment: There is no sense in using a mapped bytebuffer when right the next operation is to copy the entire buffer into a heap bytebuffer. That’s exactly what `read` does.

Comment: @VGR - If you'll make your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be sufficient:

```
return files.stream().map(f -> readRawFile(f, numDataPoints, dataPacketSize));
```

…if, that is, you are willing to remove `throws IOException` from the readRawFile method’s signature. You could have that method catch IOException internally and wrap it in an [UncheckedIOException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html). (The problem with deferred execution is that the exceptions also need to be deferred.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no laziness possible for the reading *within* the a file as you are reading the entire file for constructing an instance of `FileDataMetaData`. You would need a substantial refactoring of that class to be able to construct an instance of `FileDataMetaData` without having to read the entire file.

However, there are several things to clean up in that code, even specific to Java 7 rather than Java 8, i.e you don’t need a `RandomAccessFile` detour to open a channel anymore and there is [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html) to ensure proper closing. Note further that you usage of memory mapping makes no sense. When copy the entire contents into a heap `ByteBuffer` after mapping the file, there is nothing lazy about it. It’s exactly the same what happens, when call `read` with a heap `ByteBuffer` on a channel, except that the JRE can reuse buffers in the `read` case.

In order to allow the system to manage the pages, you have to read from the mapped byte buffer. Depending on the system, this might still not be better than repeatedly reading small chunks into a heap byte buffer.

```
public FileDataMetaData readRawFile(
    File file, int numDataPoints, int dataPacketSize) throws IOException {

    try(FileChannel fileChannel=FileChannel.open(file.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
        long fileSz = fileChannel.size();
        MappedByteBuffer bbRead=fileChannel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fileSz);
        List<DataPacket> dataPacketList = new ArrayList<>();
        while(bbRead.hasRemaining()) {
            int channelId = bbRead.getInt();
            long timestamp = bbRead.getLong();
            int[] data = new int[numDataPoints];
            for (int i=0; i<numDataPoints; i++) 
                data[i] = bbRead.getInt();
            dataPacketList.add(new DataPacket(channelId, timestamp, data));
        }
        return new FileDataMetaData(file.getCanonicalPath(), fileSz, dataPacketList);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Building a Stream based on this method is straight-forward, only the checked exception has to be handled:

```
public Stream<FileDataMetaData> readBinaryFiles(
    List<File> files, int numDataPoints, int dataPacketSize) throws IOException {
    return files.stream().map(f -> {
        try {
            return readRawFile(f, numDataPoints, dataPacketSize);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("", e);
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't need laziness for the contents of an individual file.  Reading the entire contents of a file (typically < 10 MBytes) is fine.  I need laziness to avoid loading all of the files at once.  I've edited my problem statement to clarify that.  Your modification to readBinaryFiles is what I need and is similar to VGR's solution.  The use of MappedByteBuffer for reading files was just a quick and dirty reuse/modification of the code that writes the files.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how performant this is, but you can use `java.io.SequenceInputStream` wrapped inside of `DataInputStream`. This will effectively concatenate your files together. If you create a `BufferedInputStream` from each file, then the whole thing should be properly buffered.

Answer (score 0):

Building on [VGR's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413512/reading-a-list-of-files-as-a-java-8-stream#comment66152927_39413512), I think his basic solution of:

```
return files.stream().map(f -> readRawFile(f, numDataPoints, dataPacketSize))
```

is correct, in that it will lazily process the files (and stop if a short-circuiting terminal action is invoked off the result of the map() operation. I would also suggest a slightly different to the implementation of readRawFile that leverages [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) and InputStream, which will not load the whole file into memory:

```
public FileDataMetaData readRawFile(File file, int numDataPoints, int dataPacketSize)
  throws DataPacketReadException { // <- Custom unchecked exception, nested for class

  FileDataMetadata results = null;

  try (FileInputStream fileInput = new FileInputStream(file)) {
    String filePath = file.getCanonicalPath();
    long fileSize = fileInput.getChannel().size()

    DataInputStream dataInput = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fileInput);

    results = new FileDataMetadata(
      filePath, 
      fileSize,
      dataPacketsFrom(dataInput, numDataPoints, dataPacketSize, filePath);
  }

  return results;
}

private List<DataPacket> dataPacketsFrom(DataInputStream dataInput, int numDataPoints, int dataPacketSize, String filePath)
    throws DataPacketReadException { 

  List<DataPacket> packets = new 
  while (dataInput.available() > 0) {
    try {
      // Logic to assemble DataPacket
    }
    catch (EOFException e) {
      throw new DataPacketReadException("Unexpected EOF on file: " + filePath, e);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
      throw new DataPacketReadException("Unexpected I/O exception on file: " + filePath, e);
    }
  }

  return packets;
}
```

This should reduce the amount of code, and make sure that your files get closed on error.

Comment: Note that the original code reads data items which are not part of the list of `DataPacket` instances. Considering this, splitting the method into two doesn’t pay off. Besides, why do you think you need to handle `EOFException` separately?

Comment: The original code only reads information that goes into a `DataPacket` instance (channelId, timestamp, and the datapoints) from the file. The other information that goes int `FileDataMetaData` is either passed into the `readRawFile` method or is derived from the `File` or `FileInputStream`.

Comment: As for the distinction in exceptions, that is a matter of style. I prefer to see the distinction in the message of the first item in a stack trace (the `DataPacketReadException` rather than have a generic message that requires me to dig through the stack trace to look at the cause of the top-level exception. EOFException means there is a data problem, while IOException means that there was an issue with reading the file. But you could totally do multi-catch if that's your style.

Comment: You’re right, the other information are not read from the stream, my bad. Still, there are operations within `readRawFile` which can produce an `IOException`, so handling `IOException` in the subroutine `dataPacketsFrom` is not sufficient…